# How to fix this flutter issue with IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: flutter, dart, intellij-idea

[image]
Flutter doctor showing issues at IntelliJ Idea. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: You can try to update all plugins. Ref: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/94940#issuecomment-994690772

Comment: I wonder if the latest version of intellij is compatible with the latest version of the Flutter plugin. In my case the solution was to downgrade intellij. But now I think the Flutter plugin is compatible. What can also help is to do "invalidate cache and restart".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. In my specific case I simply:

1. Downgraded to version 2021.2.4
2. Cleared the download cash.
3. Restarted my machine
4. At this point, Flutter Doctor was no longer returning an error. (But I was in the old version of IntelliJ IDEA).
5. Then I reinstalled the new version 2021.3.
6. Cleared the download cash.
7. Updated all plugins, invalidate caches and restart.
8. Upgrade Flutter to 2.8.1.
9. Restarted my machine.

Now I have no more errors.

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on macOS 12.1 21C52 darwin-arm, locale fr-BE)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2021.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few `step` to follow that may help you

1. Close the editor
2. Go to console
3. Set the path of your Editor to flutter directory by using this command

   flutter config --android-studio-dir="**Path of your code editor**"

make sure that you have double quotes around the path.